# c# Chart Label font / Position

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, charts, aspx-user-control

I made a chart in an .aspx page in Visual Studio using C#.
I have been unable to costumize the Axis Labels, They are way too small to be seen.
here's how they look like in the "final" product

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rk7UO.jpg

As you can see the labels describing what the columns are and the Y and X axis text are really small.
I can't seem to find a way to make these look bigger.

I don't really have any code to show, since the Chart info comes from SQL and is binded to a DataTable.

This is all I have

```
Chart1.Series["vendas liquidas"].XValueMember = "ANO";
        Chart1.Series["resultado liquido"].XValueMember = "ANO";
        Chart1.Series["capital proprio"].XValueMember = "ANO";

        Chart1.Series["vendas liquidas"].YValueMembers = "VALORES";
        Chart1.Series["resultado liquido"].YValueMembers = "VALORES2";
        Chart1.Series["capital proprio"].YValueMembers = "VALORES3";


        Chart1.DataSource = transposedTable;
        Chart1.DataBind();

        Response.ContentType = "image/Png";
        Response.BinaryWrite(CreateChartImage(Chart1).ToArray());
        Response.End();
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Unrelated note about the tag [tag:visual-studio]. If you read the description, it says *DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*, so it should not be used in this question.

Comment: What?
This is an user control from Visual Studio C# Toolbox, Why wouldn't I tag it has visual studio? 
I'm working with visual studio interface and properties and user controls.

Comment: Please read the tag description, in the bit before my previous quote, it says *"Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality."* This question is *not* about Visual Studio features or functionality, it's about how to configure an ASPX control. It has nothing to do with Visual Studio itself - for example, no part of this question would be any different if you were doing exactly the same thing using a different IDE.